# Calculate $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{3}{11}(5x_1, x_2)$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

If the joint density of these two random variables is given by $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{3}{11}(5x_1, x_2)$ for $x_1 > 0, x_2 > 0$ and $x_1+2x_2 < 2.$
Use the distribution function technique to find the probability density of $Y = X_1 + X_2$.

What I have tried:

$$\begin{align*} X_2 &= Y-X_1 \\
&= \int_0^y\int^{y-x_1}\frac{3}{11}(5x_1, x_2)dx_2dx_1 \end{align*} $$

This integral is for when $0 < y < 1$

The following is when $1 < y < 2$

$$\begin{align*}(Y-X_2) + 2X_2 &< 2 \implies X_2 < 2-Y \\ 
X_1 - 2(Y-X_1) &< 2 \implies X_1 > 2(1+Y) \\
\int_0^{2-y}\color{red}{\int_{2-y}^{2(1+y)}} \frac{3}{11}(5x_1, x_2) d x_1 d x_2 \end{align*} $$

However, this does not produce the solution and the error seems to be with the red integral. How do I go about deriving the correct integral for this distribution?